# PyCharm two python versions at the same time

Tags: pycharm

I have a PyCharm project and some files are only working with python 2.7 while others work only with 3.6, however, I have to set one python version for whole project.

Is it possible to set for example python 3.6 for whole project and at the same time force some of the files to run with python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you check this : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html?
Also can I know why you can't translate all your code to python3?

Comment: You sure have last version of CPLEX? Last version may support python 3.5 3.6